# CSS - 5 fluid columns with 6 fixed separators, how to get them to equal 100% of containing div?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to achieve a design that has five columns with fluid width, but also incorporates separator divs (with background images so they're a fixed size). There has to be a way to get these columns + the separators to equal 100% width so then I can have the footer expand and contract with the content correctly.

I've looked at code for a fixed div floated against a fluid div, but can't seem to expand the idea of negative margins to 5 fluid columns with 6 fixed separator divs.

Here's what I have..

```
<div class="content">
 <div id="column-container">
  <div class="sep"></div>
  <div class="col_one"></div>
  <div class="sep1"></div>
  <div class="col_two"></div>
  <div class="sep2"></div>
  <div class="col_three"></div>
  <div class="sep3"></div>
  <div class="col_four"></div>
  <div class="sep4"></div>
  <div class="col_five"></div>
  <div class="sep5"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS is something like

```
.sep{
width:26px;
position:relative;
margin-top:-20px;
height:1113px;
float:left;
background-image:url('images/sep.png');
} // other sep divs are the same just using a different sep background
#column-container .col_one,#column-container .col_two,
#column-container .col_three,#column-container .col_four,
#column-container .col_five{
height:1090px;
overflow:hidden;
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 16.8%; 
float: left;
}
#content{
min-width:975px;
width:80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I think you've got an extra `</div>` there, closing your column-container. It would also be useful to know which browsers you aim to support with this layout. Older IE's definitely have problems with turning a percentage into a pixel value.

Comment: I fixed those errors, sorry about that.. I'd like it to work ie 8+ and  on relatively new gecko/ webkit browsers ( safari, FF, chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1:** Spend the rest of the week trying to figure out how to do this in javascript and never be completely satisfied with the result.

**Option #2:** Change the html structure a little.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #main_container {
        background-image:url('images/sep.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        padding-left:26px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .column {
        width:20%;
        float:left;
        background-image:url('images/sep.png');
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        background-position:top right;
    } .column_padder {
        padding:4px 30px 4px 4px;
    }
</style>

<div id="main_container">
    <div class="column"><div class="column_padder">Lorem ipsum de color sit amet. Consectatur adipising elit.</div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="column_padder">Cut back on those dirty cheeseburgers, Randy!</div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="column_padder">asdf</div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="column_padder">asdf</div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="column_padder">asdf</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: obviously, paddings and such will need adjusted for your own needs.

Comment: Awesome, had to fiddle a bunch before I responded, but this is working out very nicely! I never even considered doing something like this!

Comment: I actually have a little bit of a problem. It seems that images don't flow the same way the text is, and they are ignoring the padding and going all the way over until the next column.. is there a way to fix this? (right now I have a width of 100%, which works, but is a little funky, i'd like the image to reveal if they have a larger browser).. and i'll upvote when I can! ( still working on rep)

Answer (score 1):

`display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` work really well here.  If you want to make sure that it's "backwards-compatible" with older browsers you could take a look at the [Holy Grail Layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm) and expand on that.

Comment: It's generally considered best practice to not use tables for layout purposes.

Comment: @tybro0103 - While that is true and a very good thing to point out, this doesn't actually use tables, simply table-like styling.

Comment: aaa I see... I spoke too soon.